# Get maximum value from MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: sql, mongodb, aggregate

I have a list of posts:

```
[{"name: "POST 1", {"name": "POST 2",}, {"name": "POST 1",}
```

I want to count the number of identical names and output the maximum number. The expected result is: {"id: "POST 1", count:2}

Now I wrote this query

```
db.Posts.aggregate([ 
    {$group: { _id: "$post.name", count: { $sum: 1 } }
])
```

The output I get is: [{"id: "POST 1", count:2}, {"id: "POST 1", count:1}]. How can I now get the maximum from this list? Without using sort and limit, because there may be several identical min.

Comment: "Without using sort and limit, because there may be several identical min." ... Why can't you use `"$sort"` and/or `"$limit"`?

Comment: Do you want to get a result with all the posts with the same maximal count? Is that the reason? Also, is the sample data a collection (`{"name": "POST 2"}` is this a sample document`?) or is this sample data a list inside one document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more option (a variation on @rickhg12hs' s answer) is using `$setWindowFields`, since `$facet` requires to group all your documents into one large document, and a document have a size limit:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
   {$match: {date_created: {
        $gte: new Date("2022-10-01"),
        $lte: new Date("2022-10-30")
   }}},
  {$sortByCount: "$name"},
  {$setWindowFields: {sortBy: {count: -1}, output: {maxCount: {$max: "$count"}}}},
  {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$count", "$maxCount"]}}},
  {$unset: "maxCount"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dgt17Rh-gxJ)

Comment: Cool!  You could even drop `"window"` and it still works.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please tell me how I can add a gte filter to the match? I'm trying to use in conjunction with $and: [ $expr: {$eq: [...]}, {date_created: {$gte: new Date("2022-10-01"), $lte: new Date("2022-10-30")}}} But I get an error

Comment: With date_created, as requested

Comment: I'm not a big fan/user of `"$facet"`, but at least in my example it's only collecting `"postsWithCount"`, not all the raw posts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get all the most frequent `"name"` values with their count.

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {"$sortByCount": "$name"},
  {
    "$facet": {
      "maxCount": [
        {"$limit": 1},
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "count": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "postsWithCount": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$_id",
            "count": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "postsWithMaxCount": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$postsWithCount",
          "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this.count", {"$first": "$maxCount.count"}]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$postsWithMaxCount"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$postsWithMaxCount"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2o14blDT9XA).

Comment: Yeah, cool. Can you tell me more please, how can I implement such a filter in your code?)
{$match: {date_created: {$gte: new Date("2022-10-01"), $lte: new Date("2022-10-30")}}}

Comment: @Cooler-cpu You could just include that `"$match"` stage as the first stage in the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please insert this filter into your code you have written?

Comment: If you will provide such sample data, we can show you how it works

Comment: In the question I wrote only one filed - name: "POST 1", but there is also field date_created: DATE

Comment: @Cooler-cpu  I only added `"date_created"` and the `"$match"` stage.  https://mongoplayground.net/p/D-S6A5yKGCT